# Error:Could not find or load main class using Javassist

Tags: java

My code can be well compiled using:

```
javac -cp javassist.jar cRepair.java
```

Than the "cRepair.class" file is generated.

However, when I tried to run it:

```
java -cp javassist.jar cRepair
```

or `java -cp javassist.jar javassist.cRepair`

The system always says:

```
"Error: Could not find or load main class cRepair."
```

This is really confusing for me...I read some related questions but still the question is still unresovled.

```
package javassist;     
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.lang.reflect.Method;
        import javassist.*;

public class cRepair {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NotFoundException, IOException, CannotCompileException{
    ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();  
    CtClass ctClass = pool.get("javassist.RemoveMethod");  
    CtMethod ctm = ctClass.getDeclaredMethod("DoubleCheck");  
    ctClass.removeMethod(ctm);
    ctClass.writeFile("C:/Users/workspace/Javaproject1/src/javassis"); 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `java -cp javassist.jar;. cRepair`

The `;.` tells it to include the current folder which is necessary if `cRepair.class` is located in the current working folder. If you are on Linux or OS X, you'll need to do `:.`

Comment: I am using the cmd window in Windows. I just tried your commands, but the issue is still there...